# Javascript .getTime() inconsistent results between between windows

Tags: javascript

I need to show a countdown timer. I get time from my server and should count down to zero, based on the following:

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
var timeRemaining = endTime - now;
.... I start the contdown timer with timeRemining
```

What happens is when I start the timer in two different tabs, the timer is off by about 2 seconds.

If I do this in one tab and another private window/tab, the timer can be different much much more.
Is there something I can do about this?

Comment: How is `endTime` set?   Are the two tabs on the same machine?

Comment: It is the same machine. I get the end time from the server as string representation of the date.

Comment: @Kokesh, Can you provide us the sample end date. Also need to see you countdown function..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var end = new Date('2015-10-27T13:00:00');
var endTime = end.getTime();
var div = document.getElementById('time');
setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var timeRemaining = endTime - now;
  var seconds = timeRemaining / 1000;
  div.innerText = Math.floor(seconds);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```